# Emulator will not show APP

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-softkeyboard

I have imported a softkeyboard APP through eclipse I have tried running it on the emulator and my app icon doesnt even show up..There are no error messages on my app or from the emulator..does anyone know why this may be happening?? I tried to see if I could change the keyboard settings on the emulator but I did not see any option for that. I have tried accessing the text message icon and the softkeyboard that appears is not mine, its the emaulators default..Please advise Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check logcat to get the error or some warning messages, please give more details about your problem :D

Comment: My goodness I just checked and I have 33 warnings the majority are deprecated, others are with programming...so can warnings stop the app from loading on the emulator and or possibly stop it from working all together...I thought only errors did that...